# Take string from cell array for name of variable in matlab workspace

Tags: matlab, csv, variables, workspace

I have a large amount of .csv files from my experiments (200+) and previously I have been reading them in seperately and also for later steps in my data handling this is tedious work.

```
co_15 = csvread('CO_15K.csv',5,0);
co_25 = csvread('CO_25K.csv',5,0);
co2_15 = csvread('CO2_15K.csv',5,0);
co2_80 = csvread('CO2_80K.csv',5,0);
h2o_15 = csvread('H2O_15K.csv',1,0);
etc.....
```

So I want to make a cell at the beginning of my code looking like this and then a for loop that just reads them automatically.

```
input = {'co_15' 5;'co_25' 5;...
         'co2_15' 5; 'co2_80' 5;...
         'h2o_15' 1; 'h2o_140' 1;...
         'methanol_15' 5;'methanol_120' 5;'methanol_140' 5;...
         'ethanol_15' 5;'ethanol_80' 1;'ethanol_140' 5;...
         'co2_ethanol_15' 5 ;'co2_ethanol_80' 5;...
         'h2o_ethanol_15' 1 ;'h2o_ethanol_140' 1;...
         'methanol_ethanol_15' 5;'methanol_ethanol_120' 5;'methanol_ethanol_140' 5};

for n = 1:size(input,1)
    input{n,1} = csvread(strcat(input{n,1},'k.csv'),input{n,2},0);
end
```

The cell in this code is 19 rows and 2 columns, the rows are all the files and the columns will contain the parameters to handle the data. Now the problem I can't find a solution for is that my first column is a string name and I want that string name to be the name of the variable where csvread writes its data to but the way I set it up now it just overwrites the string in the first column of the cell with the csv data. To be extra clear I want my matlab workspace to have variables with string names in the first column containing the data of my csv files. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *actually* want to do this. [Even the](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5) Mathworks [will tell](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/01/04/more-in-eval/) you [not to do this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html?searchHighlight=eval#moreabout). If you are trying to use variable names to keep track of related data like this, there is *always* a better data structure to hold your data.

One way would be to have a cell array

```
data = cell(size(input(:,1)));
for n = 1:size(input,1)
    data{n} = csvread(strcat(input{n,1},'k.csv'),input{n,2},0);
end
```

Another good option is to use a `struct`. You could have a single `struct` with dynamic field names that correspond to your data.

```
data = struct();
for n = 1:size(input,1)
    data.(input{n,1}) = csvread(strcat(input{n,1},'k.csv'),input{n,2},0);
end
```

Or actually create an array of structs and hold both the name *and* the data within the struct.

```
for n = 1:size(input, 1)
    data(n).name = input{n,1};
    data(n).data =  csvread(strcat(input{n,1},'k.csv'),input{n,2},0);
end
```

If you absolutly insist on doing this (again, it's is very much *not* recommended), then you could do it using [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html):

```
for n = 1:size(input, 1)
    data = csvread(strcat(input{n,1},'k.csv'),input{n,2},0);
    eval([input{n, 1}, '= data;']);
end
```

Comment: And if I do actually want to do this? how would you do this with eval function because I can't get it working. Sorry for being so stubbern but I've never worked with struct and it seems that i need to change all my data handeling after as well which i don't have time for now

Comment: @Terranees I have updated it with a solution. Again, if at all possible use one of the first three approaches.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the first three approaches when I have a bit more time