# MATLAB: Change a known string to a variable name

Tags: matlab

I am working on a Matlab script and I am running in the following problem:

Within a loop, I am creating a string by using `strcat`. This string is actually the name of a variable. However, it is still classified as a string and therfore I cannot use it in my while loop.

Hence, my question is: how do I change a string to a variable within the frame of MATLAB?

This concerns the following piece of code:

```
WingType = strcat(Airfoiltype,TwistType);
AR = Input.Surface.AR;
Sweep =Input.Surface.SweepQC;
AR_vec = [5 6 8 10];


switch WingType


case 'UncamberedUntwisted' %% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Data_vec =['X5' 'X6' 'X8' 'X10'];
load('UnsweptUncambered.mat')

if Sweep <= 0 || Sweep >= 50

        Inflex_Ratio = 1;



elseif Sweep > 0 && Sweep < 50


                if  sum(ismember(AR_vec,AR)) ==  1;

                    pos = find(ismember(AR_vec,AR)==1);
                    AR_data = Data_vec(pos);
                    interpvec1 = strcat(AR_data,'(:,1)');
                    interpvec2 = strcat(AR_data,'(:,2)');

                    Inflex_Ratio = interp1(interpvec1,interpvec1,Sweep,'linear');

                end
```

for example: I want to create the variable `X5(:,1)` and `X5(:,2)`. These are now stored in the variables `interpvec1` and `interpvec1` respectively. However, they remain a string and thus i cannot use it with the `interp1` command.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please do not do this. Use a cell array or other structure to hold your data.

Comment: @Suever Would you care to explain? Why is it not recommended to do this?

Comment: Please read the linked post above. There are three links to the MATLAB documentation and associated blogs that explain why it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually store the value of e.g. `X5(:,1)` in `interpvec1` you can use the `eval` command:

```
eval(['interpvec1 = ' AR_data '(:,1);']);
```

I hope this solves your problem. Note however, that the eval command generally is not very fast, is difficult to read and debug.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work for me now. However, I do understand the drawbacks of using the eval command. Nevertheless, thank you

Comment: @BalrajBoyal They mentioned two reasons in their post and if you actually go read the [first sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36966657/670206) of the post I mentioned above you'll understand.

Comment: @BalrajBoyal The most immediate reason is that it is very likely that the next question you will ask will be "I have these variables `X5`, `X6`, `X8`, and `X10` and I need to access them all in a loop. How do I do that?" And the only answer will be more `eval` rather than simply looping over the indices of a matrix like you would in a properly structured program.

Comment: @Suever please read my post carefully, I've posted that 'I do understand the drawbacks'.